# What's the best way to parse a float value from []bytes?

Tags: go, byte, data-conversion

I have a function that simply reads a file with `ioutil.ReadFile()`. The type returned is `[]byte`, although the value itself can be represented as a float.

I am converting the `[]byte` in this manner (where `value` is the `[]byte` being returned from a function that reads a file):

```
var floatValue float64
fmt.Fscanf(bytes.NewReader(value), "%f", &floatValue)
```

Is this really the only way to extract/parse a valid float value from a `[]byte`? There's a similar [discussion](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/2632) but looks like it didn't really go anywhere.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseFloat (a []byte value can be converted to a string)

Comment: That will still work with byte? I swear I tried that last night. Will try again when back at desk. Thanks...

Comment: ... well first you need to convert the byte slice to a string, just like in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use [`strconv.ParseFloat`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseFloat) for this, just converting your `[]byte` to a string first. This would surely have less overhead than creating a reader and scanning with a `scanf`-like function.

```
sb := []byte("3.1415")
s := string(sb)

f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(s, 64)
if err != nil {
    panic("whoops!")
}

fmt.Printf("%f\n", f)
```

Output:

```
3.141500
```